# render out a list of elements from a list in Javascript React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, javascript-objects

i have two lists. I only want to render out the objects of list2 whose id == 2,3,5 & 7.
**in my project the lists are too big, which is why it's very important that the solution is very optimized & doesn't take much time.! thanks in advance**

```
const list1 = [2,3,5,7]
const list2 = [{id:1,name:Ronaldo},{id:2,name:Johny Depp},{id:3,name:Mr.Bean},{id:4,name:Messi},{id:5,name:Jennifer Anniston},{id:6,name:Ted Mosby},{id:7,name:Regner},{id:8,name:Thor}]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own (other than posting invalid syntax)?

Comment: you can use the filter function in list2 and check the id is included in list1 or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a filter - if the list 2 item id is in list 1 render it, if not ignore it:

```js
const listToRender = list2.filter(item => list1.indexOf(item.id) > -1)
```

Comment: one last favour... the data in those lists are coming from an api through fetch. so i want this to run only when the fetch is comlete. i tried using async in the filter but it's not filtering. how can i solve this??

Comment: See here - you need to post a question with code, what you have tried and what exactly you need help with. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

We can do it in O(N) time if we put the values of list1 into a set for O(1) lookup:

```
function filterList(list1, list2) {
    let itemSet = new Set(list1);
    let listOutput = list2.filter(x => itemSet.has(x.id));
    return listOutput;
}
```